# MVC 4 simple reroute, how?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do something seemingly simple in MVC 4:

I get a request on a route that looks like this

> data/* whatever *

I would then like to reroute this to the following:

> Content/data/* whatever *

I guess this should be done with the `routes.MapRoute` in `RouteConfig.cs`, however I cant figure out how.

Comment: So the desired result is that the user will end up at `content/data/some-page` if they enter `data/some-page`?  If so, I think you're going to want to do an http redirect.

Comment: This is essentially what I want yes. Wouldn't that best be done with a Route?